# FireFox is not working proper with URL.revokeObjectURL

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, download, blob

I am still getting into JavaScript and got a problem I do not understand.

The Code:

```html
function loadDocumentFromResponse(requestObject, filename){
 console.log('Response from Server gets analyzed...');      
 if( typeof URL === "function" ){        
  console.log('Will use the URL function to revoke an object url');
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(requestObject.response);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', url);
        a.setAttribute('download', filename);
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      // is working with chrome and gets me a download which works
        // firefox also gets into this tree but it does nothing!
 }else{
  // IE, Maxton, Safari and Opera are throwing an Exception, will figure out whats wrong, later....
  console.log('Function URL ist unbekannt');
 }
}
```

My problem is actually the IF case... Where chrome is exactly doing what I expect, it gives me a download. But Firefox, gots the function URL. too and does not create a download from the blob response...

Whats my fault? And any hint for IE, etc.?

cu

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The only solution I came up with so far is creating a timeout that revoke the objectUrl after a few minutes, just to free up memory.

Comment: I'm seeing this too in Firefox 37/OSX, no add-ons.

Comment: Can you include the headers from the response, and also verify whether or not the document request is sent to the same origin as the page this script is executed from?

Comment: @Tim-Erwin I'm having this issue and your suggestion fixed it. It seems Firefox executes the revokeObjectURL before the click event is actually processed (since it's likely async?).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues at play here:

1. it's likely that the `Content-Dispostion` header in your server response has a value of `inline` instead of `attachment;filename=somefile.ext`
2. The `download` attribute is only respected when on the same origin

Since this works in Chrome, I would tend to rule out the second issue. This means that this is likely due to the `Content-Disposition` header in the original response from the server. I followed these steps to diagnose:

1. Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for the Download attribute feature support, since it's an HTML 5 spec. It *is* supported in Firefox, but not at all in IE.
2. Checked the mozilla docs on the [implementation details of the download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

(Note, these steps are helpful since you're a beginner, eventually you'll just know this stuff. These are two very important resources/steps whenever you encounter a problem that has different behaviors in different browsers)

Firefox prioritizes the header in the document response over the value set on the `download` attribute, whereas Chrome prioritizes the `download` attribute over the `Content-Disposition` header's value.

You'll have to ensure the responseObject include a header for `Content-Disposition: "attachment;filename=somefile.ext" (replace with your own filename and extension)